# Netflix Archaius and a REST ConfigurationSource

Tags: rest, netflix, netflix-archaius

Netflix state on the Archaius [Overview](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Overview) page that

> Each Configuration can be sourced from a Configuration Source such as: JDBC, REST, .properties file etc.

However, I can't find any reference in the Javadocs to an existing REST-based ConfigurationSource.

Anyone see what I'm missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archaius can be sourced with a REST source. Internally, Netflix is using such a mechanism. However, this part hasn't been Open sourced yet. We have that on the roadmap but no particular timeline yet on when we can release it to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Rapid7 has released under the APL their own REST based configuration manager for Archaius called [Conqueso](https://github.com/rapid7/conqueso).

You can see how to configure Archaius to use Conqueso through its [Java client](https://github.com/rapid7/conqueso-client-java#configuring-archaius-to-use-conqueso).

Perhaps you can leverage this project, or get ideas for your own implementation.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Jeff, I will certainly take a look!
Kind regards